# How to identify that Chosen plugin initialized on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Is there a standard way to know that `jQuery` plugin already initialized at specific HTML element?

I want to make some actions if for example `select` element is under Chosen plugin.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#elementId").data("chosen");
```

This will return the chosen object assigned to the element, or undefined if not assigned.

Note: For other plugins or JQuery versions I worked with, you may need to check the plugin name suffixed with "Obj":

```
$("#elementId").data("pluginNameObj");
```

Comment: This is accurate. Thanks for providing this.

Answer (score 0):

use this `$('select#elementID').attr('data-rel');`
if it gives you the value "chosen" then the `select` element is under chosen plugin.